# An item of two is duplicated in ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, menuitem

I've created a menu containing only 2 items. However there is a difference between how they are displayed on an emulator and on a real device. For some reason an item is displayed twice on the real device.

Here how it looks on the emulator:

[image: On emulator]

On the real device:

[image]

Why is it so? I've read suggestions on this forum to use `menu.clear()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've not tried hard enough. I noticed that I had to call `menu.clear()` in the fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` and not in the activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. I should have mentioned in the question that I use a fragment.

After that the look of the menu items became the same on both: emulator and real device. 2 items and 2 icons.

Answer (score 0):

**Beside the answer above which creates a root activity**

It seems that you are adding two fragments two your app at once:
if that is the main activity and that activity has the following codes together

```
   if(savedInstanceState == null){
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, new MainActivityFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

and

```
<fragment xmlns:="http://schemas..com/apk/res/"
...
android:name=" (YourPackageName).MainActivityFragment"
```

then you should remove the first code because no need to add the fragment twice